# Google Earth Browser Plugin not loading KML file in some browsers

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

code:

```
google.load("earth", "1");

function gemap_init()
{
  google.earth.createInstance('gemap', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(instance)
{
  try {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

    console.log(ge.getPluginVersion());

    google.earth.fetchKml(ge,
      'http://example.com.au/maps/example.kml',
      function (kmlObject) {
        if (kmlObject) {
          ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        }

        if (kmlObject.getAbstractView() !== null) {
          ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function failureCB(errorCode)
{
  alert(errorCode);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(gemap_init);
```

for some reason this is working in every browser on my PC - but when I test on random computers and browsers around the office it is failing to display the markers or move the camera from the kml.

operating systems and browsers range from XP to Vista, and using FF, Chrome, IE7, IE8 - there is no pattern to the failure.

failing plugins are the same version as working plugins.

this is becoming a hair-pulling event for me as i just can't see where the fail is.

EDIT:

just to make clear - it is working in all those browsers and all those OSs - but not always, and not consistently...

there is no change in the javascript or kml between it working and not working.

the kml is a valid document

all browsers report that they are using the same plugin version

Comment: Which browsers does it work on?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the error console?

Comment: it has worked in FF, Chrome, IE7 and IE8 - and it has worked on XP, Vista, and Windows 7 - just not all the time and not all browsers on the same computer. there are no errors in the firebug console - just the plugin version, which is the same everywhere we've tested (on 8 different computers) - this is the irritating thing.

Comment: Your code looks just fine. I'm guessing either the server or plugin is timing out. (1) Have you tried using network links? (2) How big is the file? (3) What net connections have you tried on?

Comment: I was testing on a server which was on our office LAN - so 100 Mbps network connection... I can't be sure, as I'm out of the office at the moment, but FireBug seems to indicate that the request is not even being sent.

Comment: 1) Is there a hardware firewall on your LAN controlling the incoming/outgoing traffic?
2) Do any of the machines have software firewalls?
3) Are the machines virus/spyware free?
4) Can you 'factory reset' any of the browsers that don't work?
5) Does it work if you boot in to safe mode with networking?
6) Does it work if you clear the caches of all the browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Fraser has reminded that this question was left open...

We have resolved the problem by appending a unique ID which is regenerated whenever the KML data on the server is updated.

This seems to bust the GE cache and we no longer have any problems with missing or out of date data being loaded in the plugin.